# find number of solution of f(x)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

$f(x)=(2\arctan(x))x + 1 - 3x$.
I had to find the number of the solution of $f(x)$ -- just number of solutions, NOT SOLUTIONS TO EQUATION --
what I did was I derived f(x) then put it equal to 0 to find maxima and minima 
$f'(x)=0$ but I can't solve $f'(x)=0$.
as $f'(x)=(2x)/(x^2 +1) +2 \arctan x - 3 = 0$
guys any help appreciated.
or am I doing anything wrong

Comment: By "a solution of $f(x)$," I gather you mean a solution of $f(x)=0$, right?

Comment: I mean I am given f(x) and I am said how times does it equal to 0 which means for how many values of x is f(x) = 0.

Comment: @Isham I am not getting what you are saying

Comment: @Isham thanks bro I will try

Comment: @isham it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to take the second derivative.  We get $$f''(x)=\frac4{\left(1+x^2\right)^2}>0$$  Therefore, $f'$ is strictly increasing and $f'$ can have at most one zero, so $f$ has at most two zeros, by Rolle's theorem.

We know that $f(0) = 1$, and 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty}x(2\arctan x -3)+1=\lim_{x\to\infty}x(\pi-3)+1 = \infty$$

Therefore, if we can find any $x>0$ such that $f(x)<0$ we know that $f$ has exactly two zeros, by the previous result and the Intermediate Value Theorem.  Now,
$$f(1)=2\arctan1-3+1=\frac\pi2-2<0$$ so $f$ has exactly $2$ zeros.

Comment: but if we know that f' is increasing than how do we know that f' has 1 zero and how does that imply by Rolle's theorem that f has 2 solution

Comment: @chandsureja We know $f'$ has *at most* one zero, since it increases.  (How could it be strictly increasing and take the same value twice?)  Rolle's theorem says that between any two zeros of $f$, there is a zero of $f'$, so if $f$ had $3$ zeros, $f'$ would have at least $2$, and it doesn't. Then we show that $f$ has at least $2$ zeros, so it has exactly $2$.

Answer (score 0):

This we can also solve by drawing the graph of f(x) and checking how many times does it cut the x-axis.

- First, draw the graph for 2x*arctan(x) which will give you a parabola opened upward.
- Then subtract 1 from the graph which will give the vertex of the graph to be (0,1)
- Then add +3x to it, this will transform the graph as shown below, and the number of points where it intersects the x-axis will be the solution.
  [Graph of the given function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6nie.png)

Here the solution is **2** as the graph intersects the x-axis two times.

Comment: but I can't plot the graph in the exam so I have figure out a way to find solution without plotting the graph

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2x*arctan%28x%29-3x%2B1%3D0) says there are no real solutions

Comment: @saulspatz but I plotted graph on desmos it crosses x axis twice

Comment: Yes, and your graph looks like the "root plot" WA comes up with.  I didn't know what to make of that.  Looks like some kind of glitch in WA.